# logical to physical address with tlb

Tags: paging, tlb

i have to make a programm which "translates" logical addresses like 16916 to physical with tlb and page table! Are there any functions made for paging or i have to find some other way like arrays or lists?

Comment: Google it and show us what you've tried till now..

Comment: i found this http://minirighi.sourceforge.net/html/paging_8c.html but i dont know if its what i need!

Comment: Can you please mention the processor type? Translation process will depend on which processor you are working on. You could try writing a program all by your self ,that will be a good exercise.You will need to refer the processor manual for this task.